# Is there any way to see on linux the USB devices on realtime?

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, lsusb

My question is simple, is there a way to see in a terminal what usb devices do I have connected to my computer in real time?
I already know lsusb, but it just show me the devices on the moment I ask it, I would like to be able to see if one connects and disconects at some point.

**Edit**: Thought the answer marked underneath gives a good alternative, in order to debug the program I was working on I found usefull useing the C++ function

```
std::system("lsusb");
```

This way I could check if I had lost or not the USB device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is, you can use the `udev` device manager for kernel.

Moreover you can define rules to detect plugged/unplugged devices you are interested e.g. in your case usb devices.

[Here](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/) is a tutorial on how to write a `udev rule`

Comment: Ok, I followed that awesome tutorial and added to the rule I was using (to change the permisions) a RUN so it can execute a script wich notifys me.
The problem now is the script, because it seems that the way that blog uses its not longer working.
How do I notify to myself that I have, infact pluged an USB? I am using the notify-send comand they explain, but as the one lauching the script is the Root it don't apear, do you know how to fix it?

And also, can I through udev rules check when somthing is unpluged from the PC?

Comment: What exactly is not working, please provide more info ? the blog also contains instructions related to `notify-send` issue workaround. Of course with `udev` you can also detect the unplugged usb devices.

Comment: The work arround seems to be outdated. For what I found in the internet the gnome-panel is no longer used and it is how they used to fix it.
Do you know if someone did update on that work arround?
Right now I am reading on DBUS which to me seems to be the key element of that work arround.

Comment: `gnome-panel` has nothing to do with your problem ! You don't have to do anything with `gnome-panel` ! You have the script running, thats it, so you are able to detect plugged/unplugged devices. Why are you diving into `notify-send` or `Dbus` ? Of course you can achieve more elegant solutions with `dbus` notification service, but I think its out of your question scope here.

Comment: The point is that, provably because I am short in imagination, once i detect with the udev if my device is pluged in and run a script, I don't know what to do with the script to actually see it as a user (as the original purpose of this is pure debuging).
Given this I thought that apart from debuging, if I where to do this nice enough this could be a good userfriendly add-on to my driver

Comment: if you want to have some user-friendly way of notification, just go ahead into the `dbus`, it provides a really nice technique for communication between the applications/processes.

Comment: For anyone interested on this subject, I continued asking in this other question:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195805/runing-notify-send-as-root)