# Running notify-send as root

Tags: linux, notifications, root, dbus, notify

I am trying to get a notification when pluging in a USB device, for this I use a udev rule to track the moment it is pluged and from there I launch a script.
The idea on the script was to use what it is explained in the [link](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/).

but when trying this:

```
pids=`pgrep -u $user gnome-panel`
```

I found that gnome-panel is not there. Googled this work arround and I found quite few people complaining that this work arround is no longer working. So I did a bit of research on the subject and came up with this (notify-plugin2.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /home/user/.dbus/session-bus/$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-0 | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= | sed -e 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//')

su user Test.sh $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

to get the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` before switching user to a non root user. This statement, if I am not wrong works, so based on the code from the link above I made this other script (`Test.sh`)

```
#!/bin/sh
user=`whoami`
title="Test"
timeout=30000
icon="~/Pictures/PicturesForPwrPoint/Pluged.jpg"

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$1

echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \ notify-send -u low -t $timeout -i "$icon" "$title"
```

For what I can see on the other code, the only problem was getting the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, and if I am not wrong, with this I can have it.

So my question is, why there isn't a fancy pop-up message on my screen when launching?

```
sudo sh notify-plugin2.sh
```

Comment: it may be interesting to see the post in report bug section
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/160598

Comment: what is your operating system ?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344377/7286) for an example function which works in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Combining [tomy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49426970/566849) with [hongo's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467258/how-to-detect-a-user-logged-in-through-gui-in-linux/40288615#40288615) elegantly solves the issue for me.

```bash
function notify-send() {
    #Detect the name of the display in use
    local display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"

    #Detect the user using such display
    local user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1)

    #Detect the id of the user
    local uid=$(id -u $user)

    sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send "$@"
}
```

That function can be used as-is in any script running as `root`, as a drop-in replacement for the `notify-send` command.

Comment: Thanks. Saved me some time. Something similar to this for the last line could work. Tested on Debian 9:

`su - $user -c "DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send -i 'Title' 'Message'"`

Comment: @ColinWa the last line in the function is actually parameterized, see that "$@"? It allows you to pass the parameters `-i 'Title' 'Message'` directly to the function itself. It's meant to be used as a drop-in replacement for the real notify-send.

Comment: I'd update line 6 to include `| head -n 1`
( Making it `local user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1} | head -n 1')` ). I had it return 8 separate users on my machine :)

Comment: On Fedora 35 the `user= ...` line did not work for me.  This works for me and I think is more general (sorry I don't know how to get multiline code format in comment)...

``` bash
function notify-send() {
     # find first X socket
    local socket=$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | head -n 1)
    # extract display name, user, and user ID
    local display=":$(echo $socket | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##')"
    local user uid
    read user uid <<< $(stat -c '%U %u' $socket)
    sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send "$@"
}
```

Comment: For me on Arch Linux, this works (simplified, one-liner version of the solution in this answer): `sudo -u "$USER" DISPLAY=":$(find /tmp/.X11-unix -type s | grep -Pom1 '/tmp/.X11-unix/X\K\d+$')" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u "$USER")/bus" /usr/bin/notify-send 'Notification heading'`.

Answer (score 18):

To send desktop notification from a background script running as root 
(replace X_user and X_userid with the user and userid running X respectively):

```
sudo -u X_user DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/X_userid/bus notify-send 'Hello world!' 'This is an example notification.'
```

This was taken from:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications

Comment: This one-liner was very handy, and used in combination with @hongo's[answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40288615/566849) solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

The notification service has been changed for `ubuntu 14.04`.

Its called now smth like `org.freedesktop.Notifications.service`

You can check [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Bubble_appearance_and_layout) for more information about `Notification On Screen Display` possibilities.

Also you can use following command line to send your own messages

> user@machine ~$ notify-send “Text of message”

Just update your script which is being launched by `udev` to use it.

---

To workaround the problem realted to running the `notify-send` command as root.

Try to run is as your normal user, i.e.

```
su <YOURUSER> -c 'notify-send “Text of message”'
```

Comment: runing in the script the 
    notify-send 
comand wont work because it will be executed as
    sudo notify-send
thats the main problem. I am going to try this service name, I will update in a couple of minutes

Comment: Ok, it seems I actually don't know what to do whit the service could you give me some indication on it?. And I can confirm that when running notify-send as root it won't show anythink, that was the whole point on the work arround I was talking about.

Comment: Update the answer with the suggestion how to workaround the `root` issue. Check it and come back in case there are quesitons.

Comment: It's nice to see I am not that lost, I already tried this one. Now I found this guy http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116536/usb-connect-disconnect-notification , thought he is using an other OS I tried this 
    export DISPLAY=":0"
but it didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

```
notify-send() 
{
    local display=$DISPLAY
    local user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}')
    local uid=$(id -u $user)
    sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send "$@"
}
```

On the uos1022 system, I can query my own window through the environment variable $DISPLAY, so as to successfully pop up the notification bar as the root user

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Fabio A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533938/14619710)'s solution. However, I noticed that it was not working consistently on my Arch Linux installation. Problem was that `who` did not display the port number for the tty1 session:

```
$ who
john       tty1         2021-03-21 09:02
```

I am running i3 via `exec startx` on my Arch installation. On the other hand, I noticed that the output of `who` on a Ubuntu desktop installation looked completely different. Here, the display number is shown:

```
$ who
john       :0           2021-03-21 09:49 (:0)
```

So I was looking for another solution to get rid of the `who` command. I found that `ps aux` contains this useful entry which contains both the display number as well as the username:

```
$ ps aux | grep xinit
john 785 763 0 19:14 tty1 S+ 0:00 xinit /home/john/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.gGcqw2rJXG
```

This is the new script I wrote:

```
#/bin/bash

xinit_pid=$(pgrep xinit)

if [ -n "xinit_pid" ]; then
    xinit_ps=$(ps --no-headers -f $xinit_pid | head -n 1)
    display=$(echo "$xinit_ps" | grep -Po " :[0-9]+ " | tr -d " ")
    user=$(echo "$xinit_ps" | cut -d " " -f 1)
    uid=$(id -u $user)
    echo "Display environment: $display $user $uid"
    sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send "$@"
else
    echo "Warning: Could not find xinit process!"
fi
```

Any other script can call this script via:

```
bash /opt/notify-send-helper Title Message -t 5000
```

On a side note: I am using `dunstify` instead of `notify-send`. `dunstify` has the advantage of being able to assign IDs to a notification: Only the newest notification for the same ID is shown.

EDIT: I used to query the process "Xorg". However, strangely enough I noticed on one machine that this process was run as root. I switched to the "xinit" process instead which works just the same but seems to be always run by the normal user.

Answer (score 1):

For me this much simpler method works:

```
dbus-launch notify-send "Header" "Message"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking into this to fix a bug with a corrupt background on restart. I wanted to add a script to /etc/pm/sleep.d/ to reset it but needed DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS to set it (gnome desktop). I found that the  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS stored in the /home/user/.dbus/session-bus/* files doesn't match the one in the users environment. But I did find that one available in one of the dbus-daemon commands.

So I was able to get DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS via the snipped below and I was successfully able to use it. Replace "[username]" with your user. Hope this helps.

```
$ export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(pgrep -a dbus-daemon -U [username] | grep -o 'unix:abstract.*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with notify-send myself lateley and got it working (under Ubuntu 16.04).

I think there are 2 aspects. The calling user has to have access to the display, where the message shall be displayed and the display has to be specified.

```
root@mymachine~# who
root     tty1         2017-06-19 16:30
<user1>  tty7         2017-06-20 07:15 (:0)
<user1>  pts/2        2017-06-20 07:42 (:0.0)
root     pts/14       2017-06-20 07:05 (<IP1>)
<user1>  pts/16       2017-06-20 07:15 (:0.0)
root     pts/17       2017-06-19 17:15 (<IP2>)
<user2>               2017-06-20 07:39 (<IP3>:2) #VNC
<user1>  pts/26       2017-06-19 18:03 (<IP3>:1.0) #VNC
```

So what worked for me was

```
su - <user2> -c "DISPLAY=<IP3>:2 notify-send hi"
```

I think by switching to the user, you use their ~/.Xauthority. When authorized, specifying the display works.

I used another way to get the authority so far. I looped through the ~/.Xauthority files of every logged-in user and collected their authorizing cookies. Afterwards using the right DISPLAY-Variable works. I even collected the cookie of the display-manager (lightdm in my case)

The ~/.Xauthority-file (after collectiing):

```
root@mymaching:~# xauth list
<HOSTNAME3>:3  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0ebdee59ee015f49066f372b00589420
<HOSTNAME3>:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  74254e326e8904419d005a05a6e95a8c
<HOSTNAME3>/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  54d4cdb35eff20375e486f88e6ac8c74
<HOSTNAME3>:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c6a07838c7456224799eedfff2be7cd5
```

My script so far (I guess it is not final yet)

```
#!/bin/bash
users="$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | grep -v root)"
rm ~/.Xauthority
touch ~/.Xauthority
for user in $users; do
   xauth_file=/home/$user/.Xauthority
   while read cookie; do
      xauth add $cookie
   done <<< "$(xauth -f $xauth_file  list | grep $HOSTNAME)"
done
for xauth_file in $(find /var/run/lightdm -type f); do
   while read cookie; do
      xauth add $cookie
   done <<< "$(xauth -f $xauth_file  list | grep $HOSTNAME)"
done
for display in $(xauth list | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d/ -f2); do
   DISPLAY=$display notify-send "$@"
done
```

Legend:
Items in <> are anonymised.
IPX matches HOSTNAMEX

Greetings
dasBaschdi