# Running notify-send as root under Wayland

Tags: linux, shell, gnome, wayland, notify-send

I need to send a desktop notification to the user from some shell scripts using `notify-send`, so i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533938) and it's working under X11 without any problem, so i tried to add Wayland support to the script by using `$WAYLAND_DISPLAY` to make it work in gnome-shell Wayland, like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

function notify-send() {
    
    #Detect the name of the display in use
    local sdisplay=$(echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE)
    if [ "$sdisplay" == "wayland" ]; then
    local display=":$(echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY)"
    else
    local display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
    fi
    
    #Detect the user using such display
    local user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1)

    #Detect the id of the user
    local uid=$(id -u $user)

    sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus notify-send "$@"
}

notify-send "hi"
```

but it's not running.

so is there a way to make it work under wayland?

(gnome-shell 3.38.5 - LMDE5(debian 11 bullseye)

Comment: which notification daemon do you have running in Wayland?

Comment: @stark i'm using notify-send (libnotify-bin)

Comment: notify-send is a client program that talks to the notification daemon run by the display manager.

Comment: @markoly I use several event notifications in various shell scripts; on Lubuntu, the notification always looked different when sudo-executed from script.  I adapted your function above into my logging/messaging system, and now all notify-send events look uniform.  I didn't realize how annoying it was until you fixed it.  :-)  Thank you so much!